# Method signature best practices - overloading vs. long name

Tags: java, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, overloading

Just wondering what are your thoughts about these two different approaches: overloading methods vs. long/verbose method names.

**Update: I am looking for a general pattern / best practice. The following is just an example.**

Given an Organisation Structure with parent/child relationships

```
> OrgUnit
> - OrgUnit
> -- OrgUnit
> -- OrgUnit
```

two methods wich use the same code in great parts to get children for an xml element.

```
// 1) only 1 level down children
getSubOrgUnits()

// 2) all levels down
getSubOrgUnits(boolean includeChildren)

// 3) alternative naming of 1)
getDirectSubOrgUnits()

// 4) alternative naming of 2)
getAllSubOrgUnits()
```

So 1 and 2 is using parameters
And 3 and 4 is using parameterless naming.

What would you go for and why? Also consider that 1) and 2) can get additional parameters which result in stuff like getChilds(true,false,null) but also 3) and 4) may get Names like getDirectSubUnitsExcludeSome()

Can be JAVA specific but a broader view on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, using verbose method name is a better solution.

- It's more understandable, your code will require less comments
- It's easier to maintain, you can change the implementation without impacting existing signatures. You still can add a new signature, without regression.

But be careful, in some situation it's preferable to add some parameters

**Example 1**

```
private List<Element> getElementsByType(MyTypeEnum type);

public List<Element> getElementsOfType1();
public List<Element> getElementsOfType2();
public List<Element> getElementsOfType3();

/* VS */

public List<Element> getElementsByType(MyTypeEnum type);
```

Both implementations are good, it depends on you, on the size of `MyTypeEnum`, on its capacity to increase in size. What do you want to expose ? Do you want the caller of `getElements***` to be able to get all type of `Element` ?

**Example 2**

```
public void log(Level l, String s, Exception e);

/* VS */

public void logInfo(String s);
public void logWarning(String s);
public void logError(String s, Exception e);
```

In this case, the second part is better. Because it more readable, easy to understand on the first look. And because when you log in `INFO` and `WARNING` level, you don't need to specify an `Exception`. So Specializing the method is a good thing. However, it's important to keep the method `public void log(Level l, String s, Exception e);` public and not private because it could be useful to use this generic method in some cases.

**Conclusion**

It really depends on the situation but if you have the possibility to add specific methods, with verbose names, which  specialize a target behavior, do it.

Comment: Good answer, also good Example from a real use case with logging. thanks.

Comment: I don't agree.    I'll write a separate reply.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that longer names is the better approach.

It does "depend", but let's clarify something:

- Two methods that do the *same* thing, but take different options should, IMHO, have the same name (be overloaded).
- Two methods that do *different* things (other than what is determined
  by parameters) should have different names.  Put another way, there
  should be one name for a general *function* (albeit with variants),
  and separate names for different functions.

It's worth noting that overloading is the almost **uniform** practice used in the JRE.

I find little advantage in the longer names in practical usage.  Granted:

```
 getSubOrgUnits()
```

Is more obvious than:

```
 getSubOrgUnits(true)
```

If I was including this in a formal API I would either give them separate names, or do the second one as a constant:

```
 getSubOrgUnits(INCLUDE_SUB_UNITS)
```

Though most IDEs allow you to see immediately see how the `true` parameter is interpreted by hovering over the method (which usually brings the Javadoc in a popup).

To me, the advantages of overloading is that it makes a *formal* association of the variants.    It also is a nicer presentation in Javadocs.

Answer (score 2):

It all boils down to flavor.

As a general practice you can go with the "The least parameters the better". It's both convenient in terms of code clarity and it actually saves stack memory (not much, but every bit is important in the long run).

Having different names helps allot with auto complete as well.

For example i would go for

```
GetAllSubOrgUnitsList()
GetFirstSubOrgUnitsList()
```

The reason for this, after get, the first letter that I write will identify what i want.

As you mentioned, if you cannot have a intuitive name, you can add default parameters.

In your example,

```
GetDirectSubUnitsExcludingSome()
```

I would replace it with a minimal set of parameters

```
GetFilteredSuborgUnits(ISuborgFilter aFilter);
```

And then, from the architecture, ask developers to implement their custom filters.
A filter can ask for hierarchial depth, certain ownership etc (you're the architect, you decide).

So, as a quick summary : KISS !

Even if GetAllSuborgUnits() will provide the same with GetFilteredSubOrgUnits(null) , giving a fast and clear alternative to a behavior is better then having a complicated name / set of parameters. After all, redundancies aren't always a bad thing :).

Comment: I choose ToYonos answer because he gives better examples. The filter parameter is a good idea but also covered in the other answer with an enum. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd call that method `getChildren()`, not `getChilds()`. :)

If you have several levels, why not introduce an argument for depth level?

```
// Get children up to depthLevel
getChildren(final int depthLevel)

// For convenience
getChildren()
```

In case of a parameterless method, add meaningful information, so other developers know whether you are returning all or only first level.

---

**Edit:** OP asked: *"So in general what approach you use, why, which use cases? could you share your thoughts about that a bit."*

This is very much opinion based. As @OldCurmudgeon stated, many libraries that process tree-like structures use dedicated methods to access the subjacent layer. This is fine, as long as you do it regularly. On the other hand, introducing a `depthLevel` argument gives you more power if you want to access a particular level of your structure. This very much depends on your usual use case.

So if it is very likely that you need to get the first child of an object often, introduce `getFirstChild()` and `getChildren()`. If it is more likely that you will access deeper levels of your data more often or you need access to dedicated levels, introduce a depth parameter.

Comment: hi, thanks. I updated the question. So in general what approach you use, why, which use cases? could you share your thoughts about that a bit.

Comment: I added further information to my answer. However, option-based questions are frown upon here, so watch out, otherwise your question might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way this kind of structure would be handled is with:

```
// Used when you KNOW there is only one child.
getFirstChild();
// Used when there may be many children.
getChildren();
```

This is the pattern used by `XOM` [getChildElements](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Element.html#getChildElements%28%29) and [getFirstChildElement](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Element.html#getFirstChildElement%28java.lang.String%29) to walk the structure of an XML file.

You can always use:

```
thing.getFirtsChild().getChildren();
```

to access deeper levels.

Comment: I am looking for a more general pattern / best practice. I somehow have the sense that "old" java libs make heavy use of method overloads with do(boolean activateX, boolean activateY, int someParam) which can result in signatures like do(boolean,boolean,int) where you have to read the sourcecode (and you have to have it ;) ) - where "newer" libs are more like doWithXAndY(int param) - hope I could make myself clear.

Comment: Documentation is key, when it comes to methods with a lot of arguments. When you introduce a new method for literally every argument, this does not improve things. Instead of having one method with many arguments you will have many methods with very little arguments. You are just shifting the problem.